# Serializing a QHash containing a custom class

Tags: c++, qt

So I have created a custom class and written the QDataStream overloads for that class and that works all fine; now I'm trying do the same for another class which has a `QHash<QString,Foo>` data member and getting an error when trying to write that into the stream. Am I not able to serialize a QHash that contains a custom class?

```
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const Bar& bar)
{
    //a is a QHash<QString,Foo>
    stream << bar.a; //results in no match for operator<< for QDataStream& and const QHash<QString,Foo>
    return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I did not have `#include <QDataStream>` included in the source file and was only forward declared. Including QDataStream resolved my problem.

Comment: @user4815162342 because I have edited it to make it so.

Comment: I see; I've now removed the misleading comment. Again, as the current version of the answer does provide an actual answer to the question, there is no reason to delete it.